# Could I access a large number of permalinks via OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

How do I access OneDrive file permalinks without having to go to each file and get the link? Ideally, I'd simply like to append the file names to a link which specifies the directory on OneDrive.

To put it another way: Is there anyway to access files on OneDrive using their known names on my local filesystem and the directory permalink on OneDrive? Ideally, it would be like switching a symlink on any Unix system:

`/usr/local/imagefiles/file_names` → `OneDrive_folder_permalink/file_names`

This is to make a bunch of files photos for a family tree available to the extended family, and I'd like to toss all the photos on my OneDrive account.

Any other suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.